# How to concatenate and loop through two columns using just Bash variables, i.e. without temporary files

Tags: bash, shell

I have two Bash variables that contain 2 columns of data. I'd like concatenate them to create two larger columns, and then use this outcome to loop in the resulting rows, having each column read in respective temporal variables.

I'll explain what I need with minimal working example. Let's think I have a `tmp` file with the following sample content:

```bash
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo foo $i; done > tmp 
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo bar $i; done >> tmp
for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo baz $i; done >> tmp
```

What I need is effectively equivalent to the following code that relies in external temporary files:

```bash
grep foo tmp > file1
grep bar tmp > file2

cat file1 file2 > file_tmp

while read word number
do
  if [ $word = "foo" ]
    then
    echo word $word number $number
  fi  
done < file_tmp


rm file1 file2 file_tmp
```

My question then is: how can I to achieve this result, i.e. concatenating the two columns and then looping across rows, without having to write out the temporary files `file1`, `file2` and `file_tmp`?

Comment: you might need `paste` or somesuch rather than `cat` if you want to get foo and bar on the same line in `file_tmp`

Comment: Why do you `grep foo` and `grep bar` but then only test `if [ $word = "foo" ]`? What's `bar` got to do with it in that case?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Given the answers and comments I got, I didn't pose the question nicely. The `if` part of the code was just part of the example I made up to illustrate how my actual problem requires doing something on the second column based on the content of the first. What this code does exactly is silly, I know. Actually I added the `if` thing altogether at the very end of my edits before publishing the question. I should have discarded it as it distracts from my actual problem.

Comment: _variables that contain 2 columns of data_ : What exactly does this mean? a variable contains a string. bash also has Arrays (associative and indexed). There is no concept of a "column" in bash. You would need at least to define exactly, what your variables contain.

Comment: By columns I mean two chunks of characters separated by a space and then a carriage return. This structure (two columns) repeated various times (as many as the number of carriage returns, which is effectively the "number of rows").

Comment: The posted code doesn't make sense so saying you want the equivalent of it also doesn't make sense. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements, fix your code if it's now what you really want us looking at, post the sample input rather than scripts to create sample input and provide the expected output given that input. What you want to do is probably simple, but the question is currently complicated.

Answer (score 3):

- Bash's `read` can take input from a file descriptor other than stdin.
- Bash has [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

```
while
    read -u3 foo1 foo2 &&
    read -u4 bar1 bar2
do
    echo "$foo1 $foo2 - $bar1 $bar2"
done 3< <(grep ^foo tmp) 4< <(grep ^bar tmp)
```

The code above is a kind of [zip function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipping_(computer_science)). Note that it doesn't address ensuring that the ordering of the two sequences is correct.

---

It's not clear why your code in the question creates and then ignores `bar` lines. If you are doing that, the code is even simpler:

```
while read word number; do
    echo "word $word number $number"
done < <(grep ^foo tmp)
```

Comment: Might be a bit easier with `grep '^foo\|^bar' tmp`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm assuming a zip function is what's being requested. merging grep wouldn't help with that

Comment: Yes, you would need to do them sequentially to separate the columns anyway unless you compared which was found by the combined grep in each line anyway. That was just a through to cut down the number of descriptors used. I'm still not entirely clear what `word number` is that is being read in the question. Assuming the file format is something like `"foo 1234\nfoo 1235\nbar 1234...."`

Comment: If the question was consistent with the text then a `case "$word" in with "foo" and "bar" would be more consistent (or at least both `if [ "$word" = ... ]`). Hopefully further comment or clarification by the questioner will make that clear.

Comment: Please forget about the `if` part of the code, which I just made up for the example to showcase how I need to take actions on second column based on the first one. That's not part of my actual problem. You are right that zipping is exactly what I need. However your solution does not run: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`. I don't understand the logic of the `<` symbols, so I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: Could you explain what the `3<` part does? It sounds like the piece of code I need but I don't yet grasp.

Comment: Read carefully 2nd paragraph in *`REDIRECTION`* chapter of bash's man page: You could use `{varname}` instead of numbers: `while read -ru "$gbar" bar1 bar2 && read -ru "$gfoo" foo1 foo2;.... ;done {gbar}< <(grep ^bar tmp) {gfoo}< <(grep...` ! ... (and care about `-r` switch of `read` command;)

Comment: `Syntax error: redirecton unexpected` is likely to happen if the shell you use doesn't understand `<( ... )` process substitution (bash itself can be built without support for it)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood, but if you want to do this without temp files, perhaps this would work for your use-case:

```
# Gather the output from the 3 'seq' commands and pipe into AWK
{ 
  for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo foo "$i"; done ;
  for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo bar "$i"; done ;
  for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo baz "$i"; done ; 
} |\
awk '{
  if ($1=="foo" || $1=="bar") {a[NR]=$1; b[NR]=$2}} 
  END{for (i in a) {print "word " a[i] " number " b[i]}
}'

# For the AWK command: if a line contains "foo" or "bar",
# create an array "a" for the word, indexed using the row number ("NR")
# and an array "b" for the number, indexed using the row number ("NR")
# Then print the arrays with the words "word" and "number" and the correct spacing
```

Result:

```
word foo number 1
word foo number 2
word foo number 3
word foo number 4
word foo number 5
word foo number 6
word foo number 7
word foo number 8
word foo number 9
word foo number 10
word bar number 1
word bar number 2
word bar number 3
word bar number 4
word bar number 5
word bar number 6
word bar number 7
word bar number 8
word bar number 9
word bar number 10
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin - excellent advice - I've edited my answer to try and explain the commands in more detail. I actually think jhnc's answer is very likely what OP is looking for, but I thought I should post this on the off chance this is actually what OP wants (it's not clear to me what the output should be)

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this ??

> ```
> paste <( jot - 1 9 2 ) <( jot - 2 10 2 )
> ```

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
9   10
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `awk` to achieve this.

```
awk '{if($1=="foo") {print "word "$1" number "$2}}' file_tmp
```

Comment: How to handle both `foo` and `bar` at the same time? Wouldn't something like `awk '/^foo|^bar/ {print "word "$1" number "$2}' file_tmp` do? (question is a bit unclear on that point)

Comment: You can extend the `if` conditions, `awk '{if($1=="foo" || $1=="bar") {print "word "$1" number "$2}}' file_tmp`

Comment: My question is specifically how to avoid using the intermediate file `file_tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

### Splitting then merging *standard input* in one operation

Of course, this could be used on *standard input* like output of any command, as well as on a file.

This demonstration use *command output* directly, without the requirement of temporary file.

#### First, the bunch of lines:

I've condensed your 1st *`tmp`* file into this one line command:

```
 . <(printf 'printf "%s %%d\n" {1..10};' foo bar baz)
```

For reducing output on SO, here is a sample of output for 3 lines by word (rest of this post will still use 10 values per word.):

```
. <(printf 'printf "%s %%d\n" {1..3};' foo bar baz)
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
bar 1
bar 2
bar 3
baz 1
baz 2
baz 3
```

#### You will need a fifo for the split:

```
mkfifo $HOME/myfifo
```

Note: this could be done by using *unnamed fifo* (aka without temporary fifo), but you have to manage *openning* and *closing* *file descriptor* by your script.

#### `tee` for splitting, then `paste` for merging output:

Quick run:

```
. <(printf 'printf "%s %%d\n" {1..10};' foo bar baz) |
  tee >(grep foo  >$HOME/myfifo ) | grep ba  |
  paste -d $'\1' $HOME/myfifo - - | sed 's/\o1/ and /g'
```

(Last `sed` is just for cosmetic) This should produce:

```
foo 1 and bar 1 and bar 2
foo 2 and bar 3 and bar 4
foo 3 and bar 5 and bar 6
foo 4 and bar 7 and bar 8
foo 5 and bar 9 and bar 10
foo 6 and baz 1 and baz 2
foo 7 and baz 3 and baz 4
foo 8 and baz 5 and baz 6
foo 9 and baz 7 and baz 8
foo 10 and baz 9 and baz 10
```

#### With some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script in between:

```
. <(printf 'printf "%s %%d\n" {1..10};' foo bar baz) | (
    tee >(
        while read -r word num;do
            case $word in
                foo ) echo Word: foo num: $num ;;
                * ) ;;
            esac
        done >$HOME/myfifo
      ) |
        while read -r word num;do
            case $word in
                ba* ) ((num%2))&& echo word: $word num: $num ;;
                * ) ;;
            esac
        done
  ) | paste $HOME/myfifo -
```

Should produce:

```
Word: foo num: 1        word: bar num: 1
Word: foo num: 2        word: bar num: 3
Word: foo num: 3        word: bar num: 5
Word: foo num: 4        word: bar num: 7
Word: foo num: 5        word: bar num: 9
Word: foo num: 6        word: baz num: 1
Word: foo num: 7        word: baz num: 3
Word: foo num: 8        word: baz num: 5
Word: foo num: 9        word: baz num: 7
Word: foo num: 10       word: baz num: 9
```

#### Other syntax, same job:

```
paste $HOME/myfifo <(
  . <(printf 'printf "%s %%d\n" {1..10};' foo bar baz) | 
  tee >(
    while read -r word num;do
        case $word in
            foo ) echo Word: foo num: $num ;;
            * ) ;;
        esac
    done >$HOME/myfifo
  ) |
    while read -r word num;do
        case $word in
            ba* ) ((num%2))&& echo word: $word num: $num ;;
            * ) ;;
        esac
    done
)
```

#### Removing fifo

```
rm $HOME/myfifo
```